# Understand rounded results after division involving floating point types

Tags: postgresql, floating-point, type-conversion, rounding, implicit-conversion

In Postgres 14, I see rounded results that do not make sense to me.  Trying to understand what is going on. In all cases I am dividing *19* by *3*.

Casting either `integer` value to a `real`:

```
SELECT  19::real /3;
```

yields a value of *6.333333333333333*

```
SELECT 19/3::real;
```

yields a value of *6.333333333333333*

However, casting both sides to `real` yields:

```
SELECT 19::real/3::real;
```

yields a value of *6.3333335*

Interestingly enough, if I cast both sides to `double precision` or `float`, the answer is *6.333333333333333*

Also

```
SELECT 19.0 / 3.0;
```

yields *6.333333333333333*

```
SELECT 19.0::real / 3.0::real;
```

yields *6.3333335*

```
SELECT ( 16.0 / 3.0) :: real;
```

yields *6.3333335*

I now see that:

```
SELECT 6.333333333333333::real;
```

yields *6.33333335*

So the real issue seems to be:

1. Why are we rounding in this weird way (I know that real / floats are inexact but this seems extreme.)
2. What data type is `19::real / 3;`

Comment: You *can* edit your question, as long as you're logged in using the same account. Use the [edit] link under the tags.

Answer (score 6):

> Why are we rounding in this weird way? (I know that real / floats are inexact but this seems extreme.)

Because `real` (`float4`) only uses 4 bytes for storage, and that's the closest possible value it can encode.

> What data type is `19::real / 3;`?

Check with [`pg_typeof()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html) if your client does not indicate the column type (like pgAdmin4 does).

```sql
test=> SELECT pg_typeof(19::real / 3);
    pg_typeof     
------------------
 double precision
(1 row)

test=> SELECT pg_typeof(19/3::real);
    pg_typeof     
------------------
 double precision
(1 row)

test=> SELECT pg_typeof(19::real/3::real);
 pg_typeof 
-----------
 real
(1 row)
```

This is the complete list of available division operators involving `real`:

```sql
test=> SELECT oprleft::regtype, oprright::regtype, oprresult::regtype
test-> FROM   pg_operator
test-> WHERE  oprname = '/'
test-> AND    'real'::regtype IN (oprleft, oprright);
     oprleft      |     oprright     |    oprresult     
------------------+------------------+------------------
 real             | real             | real
 money            | real             | money
 real             | double precision | double precision
 double precision | real             | double precision
(4 rows)
```

For combinations of types that have no exact match here, Postgres finds the closest match according to its [operator resolution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-oper.html#id-1.5.9.7.4) rules. Postgres aims to preserve precision, so the ***only*** division that produces `real` is `real / real`. All other variants produce `double precision` (`float8`). (`money` being a corner case exception.)